# HWIOauth Facebook OAuth token request very slow

Tags: php, facebook, symfony, oauth, hwioauthbundle

I am using the Symfony2 HWIOauthBundle to provide federated sign-on for my website.  Over the last week, two service providers (LinkedIn and Facebook) have gotten very slow when my server queries them for an access token.  The response from these providers for the access code is quick (<500ms).  I am not experiencing any issues with Twitter, Google or Microsoft. Symfony and all of the installed bundles are up to date.

LinkedIn is manageable at ~10 seconds, but Facebook takes 4-5 **minutes** to answer with an access token.

I've checked the server logs, and the only error is that the cURL request times out (currently set to time out after 600 seconds).  I also know that my server is only requesting ~100 tokens from Facebook per day, so I don't think that I'm being rate limited.

I'm at a loss as to what could be causing this. Can anybody help?

Edit: if it helps, I am requesting these permissions: public_profile,email

Answer (score 0):

I seen something similar when I used some proxy server. Maybe that's the problem?